# RegEx: matching and replacing ABC in "AB ABC D"

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need advice on this snippet

```
$text = preg_replace('|(A.*)?A(.*)C|', '$1foo$2bar', $text);
```

This will match ABC in "AB ABC D", and replace it with "AB fooBbar D"; as you can see this matches the "AB " part at the beginning as well, which I have to repeat in the replacement string with $1, in order not to lose it.

Is this the best way to get such a result?

Is there a flag X such that

```
$text = preg_replace('|A(.*)C|X', 'foo$1bar', $text);
```

produces the same result?

I hope I've been clear

Thank you!

**EDIT**: Consider A,B,C as atomic strings of arbitrary characters, they can contain whitespaces as well

Also, the presented example is in fact buggy, as it matches only the second "ABC" in "ABC ABC".

**EDIT2**: I'm sorry, I've probably explained the problem very badly. The point is I'd want to match **whatever** is between two A,C string, so that there is no substring A in the match

Again thanks

Comment: Next time, you should come up with a real-world example. :-) Those made-up "ABC" examples are not ideal (as you've seen).

Comment: What should the desired output be for "A AABCC C"?

Comment: @NoWhereMan: Can you explain why a simple preg_replace('|A(B)C|', 'foo$1bar', $text) doesn't work?

Comment: @Tomalak: yes you're right, I apologize
@Zach : A AABCC C should return either "A AfooBbarC C" or "A AfooBBCC bar"

Comment: @Zach: B might contain A

Comment: @NoWhereMan: I still don't understand your requirement. Why should we be concerned that B might contain A?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've probably explained the problem very badly. The point is I want to match whatever is between two A,C string, so that there is no substring A in the match.

Comment: Please give us a real world example of what you are looking for and not just an ABC example. This might be misleading.

Comment: I am beginning to think that this is one of those "regex HTML parser questions" in disguise. If that's the case, please NoWhereMan, say so now so we can stop racking our brains in vain.

Comment: it is an attempt to replace an old bbcode parser with a compatible solution using regexes; there are no suitable classes in terms of licenses available; and also I wanted to learn something more about regexes.

Comment: @NoWhereMan: The first thing to learn about regexes is that they are totally and completely unsuitable to parse any language whatsoever. Be it HTML or BBcode, you will not get it right with regex alone. Use a parser. Or write one.

Comment: @Tomalak: Actually I've been using a 'real' parser http://www.christian-seiler.de/projekte/php/bbcode/index_en.html
but I though it was overkill, I'll probably reconsider. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the question has been clarified, try this expression:

```
preg_replace('/(?:A)+(.+?)(?:C)+/', 'foo$1bar', $text)
```

An example:

```
$A = 'abc'; $B = '123'; $C = 'xyz';
$text = "$A$B$C $A$A$B$C $A$B$C$C";
echo preg_replace("/(?:$A)+(.+?)(?:$C)+/", 'foo$1bar', $text);
```

Comment: A(.+?)C
matches A C B C as well, and [^C] it's not suitable since C is in fact a string (e.g. it might be 'foo'); sorry, I've probably edited the description while you were giving your answer

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
$text = preg_replace('|A(\S*)C|', 'foo$1bar', $text);
```

The `\S` matches a non-whitespace character, so you won't replace across different words.

---

After seeing some of the OP's comments, I'll hazard another guess:

```
$text = preg_replace('|A(B)C|', 'foo$1bar', $text);
```

Comment: Nice, but I needed to match white space as well, I meant ABC as arbitrary A,B,C strings, I should probably explain that better.

Answer (score 1):

Use the non-greedy version of the `*` quantifier :

```
$text = preg_replace('|(.*)(A.*?C)|', '$1foo$2bar', $text);
```

Comment: I've tried that and it matches AABC in "AABC", and not only ABC